# Implementing twitter like user flow interface?

Tags: php, javascript, twitter

I want to implement twitter like user flow interface, i.e. when user goes to 
`http://twitter.com/#!/abc` the page is loaded.
I have tried to implement this at:

```
http://forum.abhibhatia.co.cc/ajax/
```

What I try to do is that as soon as page loads, the url is splitted by "#!/" and secon part is loaded so that `http://forum.abhibhatia.co.cc/ajax/posts.php` can be accessed at `http://forum.abhibhatia.co.cc/ajax/#!/posts.php` . The problem I am facing is that the page does not change after I redirect user using `window.location`
it does not work. I have not tried any other way to redirect users yet.
here is the javascript function used:

```
function geturl(){
    var url=window.location.toString();
    var a=url.split("#!/");
    if(a.length==1)
        a[1]='data.php';
    return a[1];
    }
function fetchPage(){
    var url=geturl();
    var xmlhttp;
    if (url.length==0&&m==1)
      { url='data.php';
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==1) document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="Loading...";
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var file=xmlhttp.responseText;//alert(file);
        var contents=file.split("<head>");//alert(contents[0]);
        var useable=contents[1].split("</head>");
        var head=useable[useable.length-2];//alert(head);
        var body=useable[useable.length-1].split("</body>");
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=body[0];
        document.head.innerHTML=document.head.innerHTML+head;
        //document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
fetchPage();
```

Comment: As a side note, hashbangs are bad. *Bad bad bad*! Try and use html5 history instead, [pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: can you please explain me why?

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Are-hashbang-URLs-a-recommended-practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look closer at the `window.location` object you can use window.location.hash but as mentioned before hashbangs are a bit old these days I'd be much more inclined to use the html5 state management with standard hashes # as a fallback.

some further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/7/Saner-HTML5-History-Management

If you really want to make a twitter style interface you should look to put the whole app on a framework which does all of this for you like backbone.js which will mean that you just need to use a REST/CRUD style data source and then will implement all of the state managemet and hash fallbacks for you.